# Digitizing dimensioning and annotations

Tags: qgis, digitizing

[image]Digitizing a utility network is feasible in QGis, but I face great difficulties to digitize the huge number of annotations and dimensioning attached to the network. I try to achieve this operation in the QGis by creating blank layer with labels but it is not convenient for dimensioning. Also, working with the composer is very tedious. Note that this operation is easy in CAD software (Autocad map for example).
Is there a plugin that could achieve easily this operation in QGis ?

Comment: What version of QGIS?

Comment: have you used cadtools? https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/cadtools/

Comment: I use QGis 2.18.19.I think cadtools is efficient for digitizing the network but it is not the case for annotation and dimensioning

Comment: Could you add an image of what you're going for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding dimension annotations can be done by adding a line and changing the style. For example:

[image]

This is a line labeled using the formula

> round($length,2)  || ' feet'

The length function calculates the length of the line in the **units of the layer CRS**. My line layer is in a CRS that uses feet as its unit, so the length is calculated in feet.

There is a white rectangular background behind the label.

[image]

label placement is set to "on line"

[image]

The end caps are added as a second symbol level, using markers on every vertex.

[image]

---

Many variations are possible by playing with different styles.

Here's what the example from above looks like if I remove the "simple line" symbol level.
[image]

Here's what it looks like with a rotation of 90 degrees, and the coordinates set to $x_at(1) and $y_at(1)

[image]

[image]

And with an arrow instead of a line:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider QAD plugin. It manages dimensions as AutoCAD does.

Comment: Well noted. Many thanks